# what is the correct way to initialize drupal collapse behavior

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I have a subform which I fetch via ajax and append to my main form.  On the server-side I wrap the subform in a fieldset with the 'collapsible' and 'collapsed' classes, drupal_render the array, and pass it back in json (SOP).  On the frontend, I can get the collapsible behavior by using the following code:

```
jQuery('#my-fieldset legend span').click(function(){
 Drupal.toggleFieldset(jQuery('#my-fieldset'));
});
```

This works, but it doesn't seem like the right way to do it.  I tried attaching the behavior using this code:

```
Drupal.behaviors.collapse.attach(jQuery('#my-fieldset'), Drupal.settings);
```

and

```
Drupal.behaviors.collapse.attach(jQuery('#my-fieldset'));
```

but neither correctly applied the behavior.

So what's the right way to initialize this behavior manually?

TIA

I think I've got it:

```
Drupal.behaviors.collapse.attach(jQuery(document), Drupal.settings);
```

---

SOLUTION

THanks prabeen giri!  Drupal.attachBehaviors makes more sense...

I did test with drupal.attachBehaviors() but maybe I wasn't using it right.  I think I was passing a jquery object as the context rather than just the selector, as seen in the example post you mentioned, if that makes a difference.  I'll play around with it some more.

I also wasn't familiar with the load() method which is good shorthand for my traditional approach...

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: Drupal.settings.basePath + url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      if (response.status != undefined && response.data != undefined && response.status == 'ok') {
        callback(response.data);
      }
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Thanks for the insight.  Very helpful.

(I'd upvote you but I don't have the rep)

Answer (score 0):

`Drupal.attachBehaviors()` is the way to manually attach behaviours in Drupal7

You can see here https://drupal.org/node/1143768 for reference.

**Updates**

AttachBehaviours gets invoked completion of any ajax request. Therefore, it reinvokes the everything thats inside

```
Drupal.behaviours.myModule = {
  attach : {
    // your code here 
    // Code here will get executed on page load and every ajax request 

      new Drupal.MyMenuList() // this will attache events and handles it 
  } 
}
```

Lets say you are using some constructor object to attach events, handle events, and other stuffs like

```
Drupal.MyMenuList  = function () { 
  $('#asdf').click(function() { 
    //
  });
}
Drupal.MyMenuList.prototype.click = function (){
  // event handler
}
```

If you don't want to use above attach behaviors, then you can use  `Drupal.attachBehaviours(new Drupal.MyMenuList())` to apply the same behavior again.